# Trouble understanding Travis CI build error and how to correct

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda, travis-ci

all of a sudden I am getting this error through TravisCI and I have no idea what to do to fix it. I see that it mentions that - python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully. However, it's my understanding that egg_info and related files have been replaced by pip and wheel.

I see that the command pip install . failed, but I have no idea how to correct this.

Is this an issue with the virtual environment that I'm using (in PyCharm I use Conda)? I'm really lost with this, so any help is appreciated.

Also, setuptools and pip are updated on my machine.

:

```
Worker information

0.14s0.01s0.00s0.01s
system_info

Build system information

0.01s0.01s0.73s0.27s0.05s0.00s0.04s0.00s0.01s0.01s0.01s0.01s0.01s0.00s0.00s0.02s0.00s0.01s0.25s0.00s0.00s0.00s0.01s0.00s0.09s0.00s0.97s0.00s0.00s6.03s0.00s3.57s0.00s2.52s
docker_mtu_and_registry_mirrors
resolvconf
git.checkout

1.09s$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=main https://github.com/REDACTED 

0.01s0.01s$ source ~/virtualenv/python3.7/bin/activate

$ python --version

Python 3.7.1

$ pip --version

pip 22.0.4 from /home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
install.1
2.45s$ pip install --upgrade pip
0.79s$ pip install .

Processing /home/travis/build/REDACTED
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error


  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 14, in <module>
        File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
          from setuptools.dist import Distribution
        File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 34, in <module>
          from ._importlib import metadata
        File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_importlib.py", line 28, in <module>
          disable_importlib_metadata_finder(metadata)
        File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_importlib.py", line 12, in disable_importlib_metadata_finder
          import importlib_metadata
        File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 471, in <module>
          __version__ = version(__name__)
        File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 438, in version
          return distribution(package).version
        File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 411, in distribution
          return Distribution.from_name(package)
        File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 179, in from_name
          dists = resolver(name)
        File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 886, in find_distributions
          found = self._search_paths(context.name, context.path)
      AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

The command "pip install ." failed and exited with 1 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```